# How can I make a label smoothly disappear after a certain time in my app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, animation

I am using Xcode to create a `Cocoa app` for `Mac OSX` written in `Objective-C`. I was wondering if I could use an `NSTimer` to make a label Smoothly disappear after a certain time after I have clicked a button.

Or I thought I could use this code:

```
- (IBAction)clickToLoadAppButtonClicked:(id)sender; {

[self performSelector:@selector(delayedLoad) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0]

}
```

All I would need to do would be to add a `void` function called `delayedLoad`. I just need to know the code to make the label smoothly disappear so I can put it in the `void`...

Please help and thanks guys :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using core animation:

```
[[myLabel animator] setAlphaValue:0.0];
```

This animates to transparent over a default period of 0.25 seconds.

See [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CoreAnimation) for some further explanation or [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/Animation_Overview/MacOSXAnimTech/MacOSXAnimTech.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004952-CH6-SW1) for the full docs.